# Displaying divs using JQuery in sequence

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display 3 divs one after another. I want them to be displayed in the sequence 1,2,3,1,2,3,.... and so on..

This is the code I am using

```
//Initially setting the divs to be hidden
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".1").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".2").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".3").css("visibility","hidden");
    myFun();
});

var x=1;


function myFun(){
switch(x)
{       
case 1:
    $(".3").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".2").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".1").css("visibility","visible");
    x++;
    break;

case 2:
    $(".1").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".3").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".2").css("visibility","visible");
    x++;
break;

case 3:
    $(".1").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".2").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".3").css("visibility","visible");
    x=1;

break;

}
//this might be wrong
$(this).delay(1000,myFun());
}
```

This displays the three divs but without delay. How do I go about giving delays and calling the same function again. Is there a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting back variable `x` to `1` in `case 3` so I assume you'd like to rotate. Therefore `setInterval` might be the right choice.

Just call `window.setInterval(myFun, 1000);` outside your function `myFun` and everything works fine.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KHVvf/

Also, classnames shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: @gdoron The W3 says `they cannot start with a digit` (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters).

Comment: You're right, I once read(here...) it applies only to ids and names.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
<div class="d d1">Div1</div>
<div class="d d2">Div2</div>
<div class="d d3">Div3</div>
```

JS

```
 cycle(1);

function cycle(seqIndex) {    
  $('.d' + seqIndex).fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('.d' + seqIndex).hide();
        seqIndex = (seqIndex == $('.d').length) ? 1 : seqIndex+1
        cycle(seqIndex);            
    });
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XUFqu/

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout:

```
window.setTimeout(myFun, 1000);
window.setTimeout(myFun, 1000);
window.setTimeout(myFun, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
var $divs = $('div');
function foo(){
    $divs.each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(i * 500).toggle(0);
    });
    foo();
}

foo();
```

But it depends on the **real** reason for the hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Why not useing display:none instead of visibility?

you can try this, is not elegant but just to explain the elements visiblity succession:

using the show() function you can set the duration and the callback to be executed after the animation ended,

give to your divs a common class so you can reference all together myclass for example, something like:

```
<div class="myclass 1" >1</div>
<div class="myclass 2" >2</div>
<div class="myclass 3" >3</div>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".myclass").hide(); //maybe is better to hide them by Css
    fadeInAll()
});

 var delay = 500;



   //Show each div in sequence
    function fadeInAll(){
        $(".1").show(delay,function(){
               $(".2").show(delay,function(){
                     $(".3").show(delay,function(){
                         fadeOutAll()
                    })
               })
        })
    }

   //Hide each div in sequence 
    function fadeOutAll(){
        $(".1").hide(delay,function(){
               $(".2").hide(delay,function(){
                     $(".3").hide(delay,function(){
                         //Loop again
                         fadeInAll()
                    })
               })
        })
    }
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sprvM/1/) this working example